# how to check memory corruption in C++

Tags: c++, memory-corruption

I have an issue in my project. Sometimes execution fails with the error "unabe to access a reading/writing  location xxxxx".
I know it is a memory corruption error. But how can I trace that error. It is failing at memory deallocation of a variable , if I comment that line it is processing fine. That is , the the memory for this variable has got released already. Earlier it was working fine, I added code recently but i didnt change anything related to this. How can I check the memory corruption fo this.

Comment: What operating system, compiler, and IDE are you using?

Comment: What platform? Either way, do some googling or search SO,  this question has been asked to death a million times.

Comment: @Amaravathi Probably there is a double deletion in your program. With just the description, it is not possible to say where the problem is. Replicate the issue to a small program and post the code here.

Comment: On Windows, for free, to find memory related issues (leaks, in paticular) you can try Visual Leaks Detector: http://vld.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 7):

Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if you're under linux, it will show you exactly what's happening if you stomp your memory.

On windows: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows).

Comment: @Amaravathi Well why didn't you say so in your original question? It would have helped vast amounts.

Comment: Having a memory corruption problem except when I run under valgrind then it never segfaults of course.

Answer (score 0):

With the information given, you'll have to step through all your code that you have added recently (if this is a recent issue) and evaluate and check each line and see if you are stomping memory.  `memcopy` is a command that can cause this type of error if you're allocating to much for the size of the item you are copying.

Make sure you are only deleting your objects(pointers) once as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, try winDbg. Its the best and very powerful.